# Hitting measure/overshoot for random walk in $\mathbb{Z}$ with heavy-tail

Tags: pr.probability, random-walks, potential-theory

Let $\alpha \in (0,2)$, (or for simplicity just $\alpha \in (1,2)$) and let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be an i.i.d collection of random variables with common distribution
$$
  p(x,y)= \frac{c_\alpha}{|x-y|^{1+\alpha}}1_{[x\neq 0]}
$$
where $c_\alpha = \frac{1}{2\zeta(1+\alpha)}$ is the normalising constant. Now, consider the random walk $\{S_n\}$  given by $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$  and $S_0=0$.

For a given $n\ge 1$, consider $\Lambda_n = [-n,n]$, I would like to know whether good bounds for the hitting measure defined  as

$$
  H_{\Lambda_n}(0,x)= P_0[S_{\tau_n}=x],
$$
where $\tau_n = \inf\{n\ge 0, |S_n|\ge n\}$. I have seen such problems under the name of **overshoot** and **undershoot** bounds. But I have not found an article dealing with the setting without a drift and with heavy tail random walks. It is easy to get very bad bounds, but then they are far from matching.

From a few simulations I made, it seems like it decays as a power of $(|x|-n)$, but I couldn't figure out what was the exponent for an arbitrary $\alpha$.

Are there good bounds known for $H_{\Lambda_n}(0,x)= P_0[S_{\tau_n}=x]$?

**EDIT**: As mentioned in the comments bellow, one can use that for $x>n$
$$
(1) \qquad
\frac{c_\alpha}{(x+2n)^{1+\alpha}} \le H_{\Lambda_n}(0,x)\le \frac{c_\alpha}{(x-n)^{1+\alpha}}
$$
and therefore for $x>cn$ for some $c>1$, we have that $H_{\Lambda_n}(0,x)\asymp n^{-1-\alpha}$. So the question is really about the remaining $x \in [n+1,cn]$. As the bounds given in $(1)$ would lead to upper and lower bounds that that do not match.

Comment: If you're interested in the regime $|x|\ge 2n$, then it's obvious that the decay is like $1/(|x|)^{1+\alpha}$: for any point in $\Lambda_n$, the probability of jumping to $x$ is within a constant factor of $p(0,x)$.

Comment: Agreed, the problem is really between $n+1$ and $cn$ for some $c>1$. Maybe I should edit the question to reflect that. But I really mean good bounds taking small $x$ into account.

Comment: So I think editing questions to change what they’re really asking is frowned upon. In this case, I don’t think the question is being changed. I’d see it as a clarification rather than a new question, but I think it is preferred to mark the edit as such (e.g. by adding a paragraph at the end labeled EDIT) in order that future readers can make sense of the comments.

Comment: So I have been doing some back-of-the-envelope calculations (I don't think I have the technical expertise to prove this). I believe that the hitting measure looks like $1/N(|x|-N)^\alpha$ for $|x|<2N$ and $1/|x|^{1+\alpha}$ for larger $x$. My rough argument is to consider jumps of size up to $N/1000$ as "small" and anything else as large. Then the variance of a single small step is something like $N^{2-\alpha}$. Thus the standard deviation coming from the small steps is of size $N$ after $N^\alpha$ steps.

Comment: Heuristically after this order number of steps, the position is uniformly distributed on $[-N,N]$. It is then the bigger jumps that are responsible for leaving the interval. If a jump is of size $N/L$ for some $L$, then my heuristic would say you have a $1/L$ chance of leaving the interval. Summing the contributions leads to my back-of-the-envelope answer.

Comment: This is an interesting approach, I will definitely try. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Hmmm - it seems my hitting measure doesn't integrate to anything close to 1...

Comment: OK - I see what I did wrong - if you make a jump of size N/L and *don't* leave the interval, I stopped keeping track of what happens. What I should instead assume you re-randomize over the entire interval in that case. I think this means my first comment (and hence your EDIT) is wrong: you are looking at where you go *conditional on leaving*, where I was looking at unconditional probabilities in each step. But I now have a new guess! Because you re-initialize if you don't escape, this just corresponds to normalizing the probability distribution I guessed before

Comment: So my revised version is the hitting density should look like $1/(|x|-n)^\alpha$ on $[n,2n]$ and $n/|x|^{\alpha+1}$ beyond.

Comment: I noticed another problem. Both of us seemed to have used that $P_0(X_{\tau_n}=x)= \sum_{y\in[-n,n]}P_0(X_{\tau_n-1}=y)P_0(X_{\tau_n}=x|X_{\tau_n-1}=y) $ $=\sum_{y\in[-n,n]}P_0(X_{\tau_n-1}=y)p(x,y)$. But the last identity is false. For instance one can check for the simple random walk that this fails. But maybe it is still asymptotically true.

Comment: By this, I mean that the expressions could be bounded above and below by each other up to multiplicative constants.

Comment: Your random walk is in the domain of attraction of a stable law/process, and thus for large $n$, the harmonic measure of the interval $\Lambda_n$ will approximate that of the stable process, which is well-known. Thus, $H_{\Lambda_n}(x,y)$ should be roughly equal to $c_n (n^2 - x^2)^{\alpha/2} (y^2 - x^2)^{-\alpha/2} |x - y|^{-1-\alpha}$. This is heuristic only, and working out the details can be quite messy if you need a bound uniform near the boundary. I think I have seen something similar in the literature, but unfortunately I do not have a reference.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki that was precisely the type of argument I was looking for. But I have not found a reference even for the hitting measure of the stable process. Do you know where I could find this?

Comment: @Kernel: For the stable process, see: R. M. Blumenthal, R. K. Getoor, and D. B. Ray, *On the distribution of first hits for the symmetric stable processes*, Trans. Am. Math. Soc., 99 (1961), 540–554. Related references: M. Kac, *Some remarks on stable processes*, Publ. Inst. Stat. Univ. Paris, 6 (1957), 303–306; and: M. Riesz, *Intégrales de Riemann–Liouville et potentiels*, Acta Sci. Math. Szeged, 9 (1938), 1–42.